# No such column 'AccountNumber' on entity 'Name'

Tags: soql

I am getting error 'No such column 'AccountNumber' on entity 'Name' when i tried to execute the following query,

> select parent.AccountNumber, parentid, subscriberid from
>   EntitySubscription where parent.type='account'

How to get AccountNumber from this query? Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use TYPEOF to get at this data (currently only a developer preview). If you need this for production code, use two queries instead of one.

```
select id, typeof parentid when account then parent.accountnumber end from entitysubscription where parent.type = 'account'
```

Comment: when i try to use the accountnumber using this statement "mapES.put(es.parent.AccountNumber,es)" i am getting an error 
"Invalid field AccountNumber for SObject Name". Any suggestions please. I am using developer edition.

Comment: That's because Parent is an SObject, so you'd have to: `mapES.put((String)es.parent.get(Account.AccountNumber), es)` (approximately).

Comment: This is a fantastic, awesome solution @sfdcfox. Thanks again.

Comment: hi @sfdcfox, i got run time error now System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.AccountNumber. Any thoughts please?

Comment: Odd. I'll try it out.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Meanwhile, i will try the another approach which you suggested using two queries.